# Export cheapest price and corresponding quantity?

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database in phpmyadmin, containing products from multiple suppliers. Each day i want to be able to export these into txt tab deliminated sheet. I have created a php file as per below, however, it is not doing what i want it to do.

This is what i would like it to do:

Export the cheapest unique sku (sku is in the name field on DB, so group by name?), which has stock (quantity) of more than 0, and to print the corresponding stock level of that particular supplier.

Example data:

```
merchant,name,quantity,totalprice
supplier A,APC-SMT1000I,1,150
supplier B,APC-SMT1000I,7,240
```

Php code:

```
<?php
  require("includes/common.php");
  $filename = "export/products.txt";
  $fp = fopen($filename,"w") or die("Could not create ".$filename." - check permissions");
  fwrite($fp,"sku\tprice\tquantity\n");
  $link = mysql_connect($config_databaseServer,$config_databaseUsername,$config_databasePassword,TRUE);
  mysql_select_db($config_databaseName,$link);

  $sql = "SELECT name AS sku,MIN(totalprice) AS minPrice,quantity FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."products` WHERE quantity > 0 GROUP BY name";


  $result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
    fwrite($fp,str_replace(","," ",$row["sku"])."\t");
    fwrite($fp,$row["minPrice"]."\t");
    fwrite($fp,$row["quantity"]."\n");
  }
  fclose($fp);
  print "Done.";
?>
```

I would have expected this code to print:

```
sku,price,quantity
APC-SMT1000I,1,150
```

However, it is printing:

```
sku,price,quantity
APC-SMT1000I,7,150
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and i apologize if i have not explained in enough detail. Let me know if i have missed anything.

Thanks

Comment: I have tested your data and query it works fine. Here is the link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/372f8/2

Comment: @ShayanHusaini. It may *work*, but only by accident

Comment: Yes, it seems to be doing the cheapest bit correctly, and i think i have figured out  that it just takes the first quantity of more than 0 that it finds, whereas i want it to print the quantity that corresponds to the cheapest price. Not really sure why it should be so complicated for it to find the cheapest, check that it has a quantity of more than 0 and if so then print that quantity, very strange. But then i dont know sql and DB's enough to know the logic. If anyone can figure out a simple way that would be great

Comment: @Strawberry Do you know how the query should look? Would be great to get it working correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
 MIN(totalprice)
```

You could keep it like totalprice and use the order by instead like here:

```
ORDER By totalprice DESC
```

Hope this works.

Final query:

```
$sql = "SELECT name AS sku, totalprice AS minPrice,quantity FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."products` WHERE quantity > 0 GROUP BY name ORDER BY totalprice DESC";
```

**WARNING:**
In PHP 5.5 mysql will be deprecated. Use *mysqli* instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery for this particular purpose. While you can order just by price ascending, chances are the real query will be a little more complex and you may want to use something like the following to allow for more options:

```
SELECT 
    name AS sku,
    totalprice AS minPrice,
    quantity 
FROM 
    `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."products` 
WHERE 
    and supplier=
        (
            select
                supplier
            from
                `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."products` 
            where
                quantity > 0
            order by
                totalprice asc
            limit 1
        )
GROUP BY 
    name
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. Stick with an uncorellated subquery.